# how to share service in angular

Tags: angular

I have an angular application with different module. Module are lazy loaded. Let's say in module A I have a service userService that I want to use in a component in module B, let's say library.component. So I have this code :

A.module.ts :

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [...],
  imports: [...],
  providers: [UserService]
})
export class UserModule { }
```

And in library.component.ts I have this import `import {UserService} from ...`

The structure of my directory is as follow :

```
--moduleA
  --service
    --user.service.ts
  A.module.ts
--moduleB
  --component
    --library.component.ts
```

What I want to know is, knwowing that modules A and B are lazy loaded is it a bad practice to import a service from A in B ?

Should I instead move the functions of userService that I use in a service in module B or maybe define a shared module.

Thanks in advance for your response.

Answer (score 1):

This is a scenario where it depends on the individuals framing their architecture and I would go in this way:

**Point1:** I would use the way you used when I dont have a lot of methods its because when we look at the closures when we access a service it creates a prototype of all the methods thats available and thats doesnot matter anyway if you have only some 3 - 4 methods

[image: Closures in my service]

**Point2:** If we have 100's of methods and calling that service in our module only for a single method is not recommended and I would prefer to go for shared module in this scenario.

This totally depends on the architecture you design :)

Answer (score 0):

One of the solution for your question is that

`@Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })`

After adding this to service, this service can be called in the other services constructor 
`constructor(private service: Service) {  }`

It was explained at https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection